# Enviar parámetros a una promesa

Tags: javascript, promesas

estoy haciendo una web y he tenido algunos problemas y pensé que la solución seria que pudiera enviar parámetro a una promesa en javascript.

Seria que yo llame a una promesa enviándole unos parámetros como si fuera una función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intuyo que habra muchas otras formas, pero esta funciona:

```js
 function miFuncion(param){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(param);
})};
miFuncion("soy un parametro").then(res => console.log(res))
```

se trata de encerrar la promesa dentro de una funcion como valor de retorno y podemos pasarle parametro a la funcion

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario, me funciono!